# Custom Authorization Attribute in .Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the code below for a custom Authorize attribute

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{  
    
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)  
   { 
    } 
    
}
```

the issue is there is no such thing as `HttpContextBase`. I have all the httpcontext `using`s as well but still yells at me. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The `AuthorizeAttribute` in ASP.Net core has no `AuthorizeCore` method to override, and `HttpContextBase` does not exists. Those are from ASP.Net (not core). This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If we want to write custom logic to authorize the user, I suggest you could consider using AuthorizeAttribute and the IAuthorizationFilter.

The IAuthorizationFilter provide the OnAuthorization method which could write some custom logic to authorize the user.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //Custom code ...

  

        //Return based on logic
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }


}
```

Besides, asp.net core recommend using the new policy design. The basic idea behind the new approach is to use the new [Authorize] attribute to designate a "policy" (e.g. [Authorize( Policy = "YouNeedToBe18ToDoThis")].

More details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/7609093).

Comment: If you want to "turn off Auth" while in debug mode - in VS - how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code like this:-

Instead of `HttpContextBase` you can use `AuthorizationFilterContext` as mentioned in example.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
  {
    //your code logic..........
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you select a scheme with this method?

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me in .Net Core 5

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues tokens;
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("saToken", out tokens);
        var token = tokens.FirstOrDefault();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            var jwtService = (IJwtService)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IJwtService));

            if (jwtService.IsValidToken(token))
                return;
            else
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Invalid Token";
                context.Result = new JsonResult("Invalid Token")
                {
                    Value = new { Status = "Unauthorized", Message = "Invalid Token" }
                };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;
            context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Please Provide Token";
            context.Result = new JsonResult("Please Provide Token")
            {
                Value = new { Status = "ExpectationFailed", Message = "Please Provide Token" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).